# Move and rename multiple subdirectories to new location

Tags: linux, bash, find, rename, mv

My directories are setup in this way:

- `dir 1`

  - `001`

    - `11-20-2001-RT SIMULATION-57976`
  - `002`

    - `11-20-2001-RT SIMULATION-30560`
  - `003`

    - `08-24-1998-RT SIMULATION-72882`

and so on for about 250 entries. My goal is to move each of these subdirectories with the string `RT SIMULATION` to another directory, i.e. `dir 2`, but rename them to their respective parent directory. So I'm looking for.

- `dir 2`

  - `001` (*this should correspond to `11-20-2001-RT SIMULATION-57976` in the above example)
  - `002`
  - `003`

So far I'm able to find these `RT SIMULATION` directories using this code
`for i in $(find /dir1/*/* -name "*RT SIMULATION*" -type d); echo "$i"; done;`

Now I need to move and rename these directories to `dir 2` based on their parent directory as specified above. Any help or pointers?

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload -Uz zmv
zmv 'dir 1/(*)/*RT SIMULATION*(#q/)' 'dir 2/$1'
```

If you have to use `bash`, and assuming a GNU system, you could do something approaching with:

```
(
  shopt -s nullglob
  ret=0
  for dir in 'dir 1'/*/*'RT SIMULATION'*; do
    [[ -d $dir && ! -L $dir ]] || continue
    parent=${dir%/*}; parent=${parent##*/}
    mv -iT -- "$dir" "dir 2/$parent" || ret=$?
  done
  exit "$ret"
)
```

BTW, see [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697) for what's wrong about your <strike>`for i in $(find...`</strike>.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` and the perl version of `rename` to do this.  For example:

First, I'll set up a testing environment:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/goldenburrito
$ cd /tmp/goldenburrito
$ mkdir -p 'dir1/001/11-20-2001-RT SIMULATION-5797' \
    'dir1/002/11-20-2001-RT SIMULATION-30560' \
    'dir1/003/08-24-1998-RT SIMULATION-72882'
$ mkdir dir2
```

Then rename the "RT SIMULATION" sub-directories:

```
$ find dir1 -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 \
    -type d -name '*RT SIMULATION*' -print0 | 
        rename -0 -n 's:(/\d{3})/.*:$1:; s/^dir1/dir2/'
rename(dir1/003/08-24-1998-RT SIMULATION-72882, dir2/003)
rename(dir1/002/11-20-2001-RT SIMULATION-30560, dir2/002)
rename(dir1/001/11-20-2001-RT SIMULATION-5797, dir2/001)
```

The `-mindepth 2` and `-maxdepth 2` options used with `find` restrict the matches to only the second level directories beneath `dir1`.  The NUL-separated output from `find` is piped into the `rename` script (which can take file & dir names as command-line args or from stdin).

For each matching directory name, the `rename` script first removes everything after the 3-digit directory name, then it changes "dir1" at the start of the directory name to "dir2".

Note that `rename`'s `-n` option makes it a dry run, so it will only show what it would do without actually renaming any directories. Remove the `-n`, or replace it with `-v` for verbose output, when you've confirmed that it does what you want.

Also note: perl `rename` may be known as `file-rename`, `perl-rename`, `prename`, or just `rename`, depending on distro and/or how it was installed. On Debian, for example, it is called `rename` and is in the `rename` package (so, `apt-get install rename`).

It is not to be confused with the `rename` utility from `util-linux` which has completely different and incompatible capabilities and command-line options.

You can tell which version you have installed by running `rename -V` (if it mentions `perl` or `File::Rename`, it's the perl version).

Perl rename allows you to use any arbitrarily complex perl code to rename files, but is most often used to do simple sed-like `s/search/replace/` operations on filenames.